# HID usb advertisement keyboard

Tags: usb, keyboard, usb-flash-drive, advertisements, hid

I got a advertisement "usb pen-drive" when plugged in autostart windows run (win + r) and writes the company website and press enter, In device manager it is shown as a keyboard. 
Does anyone know how I can reprogram the keypresses so instead of writing the companys website it presses other keys,

Any other useful/fun thing I can use it for?

Thanks!

Comment: No ones have any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at the inside of the pendrive. It's probably a microcontroller, acting as a HID device. You would need to find the manufacturer/make to find a suitable programming kit.